# Git: как обновить рабочую директорию подобно hg up -C в меркуриал

Tags: git, update, mercurial

Раньше работал с mercurial, но сейчас с git. возникли некоторые проблемы, т.к. git все таки немного отличается.

Не могли бы вы подсказать, как можно обновить репозиторий git до последнего комита, отбрасывая все изменения и конфликты, как это делает например `hg up -C` в меркуриал

Мне советовали команду `git checkout -f`, она выводит вот такое сообщение https://screencloud.net/v/x2p5 и после применения этой команды файлы в рабочем каталоге не обновились.

Comment: вы хотите изменить файлы в рабочем каталоге или всю локальную историю тоже стереть?

Comment: обновить файлы в рабочем каталоге

Answer (score 2):

согласно документации, `hg up` с опцией `-C` просто отменяет незакоммиченные изменения (discard uncommitted changes).

примерно то же самое делает и команда:

```
$ git reset --hard
```

---

а текст сообщения (которое почему-то вставлено не текстом, а картиной), говорит, что ваша текущая ветка отличается от ветки `origin/master`, и указано, сколько уникальных коммитов содержится в той и другой ветке.

---

дежурное напоминание для специалистов по *subversion*, *mercurial* и т.п.:

в *git* ветка (*branch*) — это не набор изменений, а скользящий **указатель** на конкретное изменение (в терминах *git*-а — на *commit*).

Comment: `hg up -C` не просто отменяет незакомиченные изменения, но также обновляет рабочий каталог до последнего комита текущй ветки. При этом, если бы обычная команда `hg up` привела к конфликтам, то `hg up -C` просто перезатрет рабочий каталог (без конфликтов)

Comment: @АнтонХороший, я опустил эту информацию как несущественную ввиду того, что в git нет понятия «последнего (первого, десятого, сотого) коммита в такой-то ветке». потому что ветка — это указатель на **один** конкретный коммит (в один конкретный момент времени).

Comment: тогда я просто не понимаю, почему файлы не обновляются ни командой `git reset --hard` ни командой `git checkout -f` =( и еще больше не понимаю почему моя текущая ветка отличается от ветки `origin/master`. т.к. `git branch` выдает что текущая ветка `master`

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команд `git status`. в комментариях это делать не надо — здесь всё сливается в одну строку. внести исправления можно, нажав [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/460020/edit) ниже текста вопроса.